# How to play audio in Unity (Click Event Trigger Cardboard SDK)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm using the Cardboard sdk and have configured Gaze Input Module in Event System. Have also added a collider to my object.

I want to look at the object and play audio when I pull the trigger on my Cardboard HMD. However, it's currently not playing.

Can you advise if the problem is with my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class Kim : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject kkhair;
    public AudioSource audio;

    void Start() {
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void speakKim() {
        audio.Play();
    }
}
```

This audio does 'play on wake' when that setting is enabled. So I know the file is ok. Just can't make it work for trigger only.

Comment: Can you confirm that your audio source component has attach valid Audio Clip?

Comment: You haven't got any code there to trigger the audio from the cardboard trigger. You need to implement the ICardboardPointer interface in your script

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an "Event Trigger" component to your GameObject.
Select your GameObject in the Hierarchy, click "Add Component", search for "Event Trigger"

Create a new event type of "Pointer Click"
Drag in your `Kim` script, and choose the method `speakKim`

Your game object should look something like this:[image]

You must also have an EventSystem in your Hierarchy. If you don't, add one by going to "Create > UI > Event System"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally figured it out. I had the audio source added to the object incorrectly. I had created an audio source in the folder instead of adding it directly as a component to the object.

Comment: I see yes you won't get any audio without an audio source component :) all the best

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Cardboard SDK, you should also have the Demo Scene made by Google. There you click a cube that teleports, using the Gaze Input Module. You can use the same mechanism to trigger your audio. The Cube gameObject in that scene has an Event Trigger component that handles the click (and highlighting) for you, and calls a method on another component of the gameObject (in this example the `TeleportRandomly()` function of the `Teleport` script attached to the Cube).

[image]

In your case, you could change the `Pointer Click` event handling to `speakKim` on your script, to make start the audio playing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful for me reviewing where I went wrong.