# How can i play an audio file then the gameobject is set to active?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this quiz game that runs with series of 5 questions per category. I want to add an audio when the user pressed the correct answer or incorrect answer. How can i make is possible that when i press the incorrect or correct answer an audio file will play?

Here's my code of the levelcontrolscript2 that runs in the question's scenes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelControlScript2 : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Get references to game objects that should be disabled and enabled
    // at the start
    GameObject[] toEnable, toDisable;

    // References to game objects that should be enabled
    // when correct or incorrect answer is given
    private int triesLeft = 2;    // Set this to 1 (leave after second) or 
    whatever when a level starts 
    public GameObject correctSign, incorrectSign, incorrectSign2;

    // Variable to contain current scene build index
    int currentSceneIndex; 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // Getting current scene build index
        currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex;

        // Finding game objects with tags "ToEnable" and "ToDisable"
        toEnable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("ToEnable");
        toDisable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("ToDisable");

        // Disabling game objects with tag "ToEnable"
        foreach (GameObject element in toEnable)
        {
            element.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }

    }

    // Method is invoked when correct answer is given
    public void RightAnswer()
    {
        // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
        foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
        {
            element.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }

        // Turn on "correct" sign
        correctSign.gameObject.SetActive (true);

        // Invoke GotoMainMenu method in 1 second
        Invoke ("LoadNextLevel", 1f);

    }


    // Method is invoked if incorrect answer is given
    public void WrongAnswer()
    {
        // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
        foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
        {
            element.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }

        // Turn on "incorrect" sign
        incorrectSign.SetActive (true);

        // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
        foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
        {
            element.gameObject.SetActive (true);

        }

        triesLeft--;
        if(triesLeft <= 0)
        {
            // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
            foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
            {
                element.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            }
            // Turn on "incorrect" sign
            incorrectSign2.SetActive (true);
            // Invoke GotoMainMenu method in 1 second
            Invoke ("GotoCategories", 1f);
        }
    }


    // Method loads next level depending on current scenes build index
    void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (currentSceneIndex + 1);
    }

    // Method loads Category scene
    void GotoCategories()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Easy");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546897/how-to-play-audio-in-unity-click-event-trigger-cardboard-sdk your question is similar to this.. Use `Event Trigger` to do this. just make a function and attached your audio clip which you want to play. then attach function by using `event trigger`. so when you click `Even trigger` will fire OnMouseDown event and play sound. 
same this do with all.

Comment: The title of your question and the content of your question are 2 different things.  Do you want to activate a GameObject when the Audio ends? or do you want to Play Audio when you click an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use ***[AudioSource](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html)*** & ***[AudioClips](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html)*** for this. Simply put these variables in script and assign the values at runtime.

```
public class LevelControlScript2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Get references to game objects that should be disabled and enabled
    // at the start
    GameObject[] toEnable, toDisable;

    // References to game objects that should be enabled
    // when correct or incorrect answer is given
    private int triesLeft = 2;    // Set this to 1 (leave after second) or whatever when a level starts
    public GameObject correctSign, incorrectSign, incorrectSign2;

    public AudioSource _audioSource;

    public AudioClip _incorrect;
    public AudioClip _correct;

    // Variable to contain current scene build index
    int currentSceneIndex;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        // Getting current scene build index
        currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

        // Finding game objects with tags "ToEnable" and "ToDisable"
        toEnable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ToEnable");
        toDisable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ToDisable");

        // Disabling game objects with tag "ToEnable"
        foreach (GameObject element in toEnable)
        {
            element.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

    }

    // Method is invoked when correct answer is given
    public void RightAnswer()
    {
        // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
        foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
        {
            element.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        // Turn on "correct" sign
        correctSign.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        _audioSource.clip = _correct;
        _audioSource.Play();


        // Invoke GotoMainMenu method in 1 second
        Invoke("LoadNextLevel", 1f);

    }


    // Method is invoked if incorrect answer is given
    public void WrongAnswer()
    {
        // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
        foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
        {
            element.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        // Turn on "incorrect" sign
        incorrectSign.SetActive(true);

        // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
        foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
        {
            element.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        }

        triesLeft--;
        if (triesLeft <= 0)
        {
            // Disabling game objects that are no longer needed
            foreach (GameObject element in toDisable)
            {
                element.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            // Turn on "incorrect" sign
            incorrectSign2.SetActive(true);

            _audioSource.clip = _incorrect;
            _audioSource.Play();

            // Invoke GotoMainMenu method in 1 second
            Invoke("GotoCategories", 1f);
        }
    }


    // Method loads next level depending on current scenes build index
    void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex + 1);
    }

    // Method loads Category scene
    void GotoCategories()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Easy");
    }
}
```

So basically assign your correct & incorrect audio clip to `_incorrect` & `_correct` to these variables. Then you will need to attach a audio source to game object in scene and assign it to a script. And then just say `_audioSource.Play()`. This should allow you to play the required clips. More details are located in unity manual on the ***AudioSource*** & ***AudioClip*** settings. The above answer works on the condition that you are just playing audio clip.

Another thing I noticed in your question title but not in body is **play an audio file then the gameobject is set to active?** If you want to activate some gameobject after playing a audio then here is solution for that also:

```
source.Play(clip);
StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(clipLength));
```

& here is the coroutine snippet:

```
private IEnumerator MyCoroutine(float clipLength)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(clipLength);
    //activate your gameobject here
}
```

[*Callback for AudioClip finished*](https://forum.unity.com/threads/callback-for-audioclip-finished.251481/) use this reference for that